# Latex. \tableofcontents with titlesec package, add extra mark after list of content

Tags: pdftex

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt,twoside]{extreport}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{First chapter}
    \section{First section}
    \section{Second section}
    \chapter{Second chapter}
    \section{First section}
    \section{Second section}
\end{document}
```

The result of \tableofcontents of standard latex command creates contents like this:
[image]

But I like add some extra words (marks) which are in circle before (after) like this:

[image]

Comment: please make a [mre]

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience, The question was modified. @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach using the `tocloft` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt,twoside]{extreport}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand*{\cftsecpresnum}{\S}


\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{First chapter}
    \section{First section}
    \section{Second section}
    \chapter{Second chapter}
    \section{First section}
    \section{Second section}
\end{document}
```

[image]